# How to remove Custom Post Type name and replace with Category permalink

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a custom post type name "Casinos". Under Casinos I have added some categories and one is 'Reviews'. When I create a post the permalink looks like http://localhost/ic/casinos/abc-casino/.

Is their anyway only on I can change the permalink like this http://localhost/ic/reviews/abc-casino/ rather then add casinos/reviews/abc-casino? So all posts under Reviews category show the same permalinks.

Comment: Can you please share the code inside your `functions.php` where you declare your custom post type? It is probably the url rewrite.

Comment: here is the link https://jsfiddle.net/k277aega/

Comment: @AntonisTsimourtos i just want rewrite url of Reviews category other category links are fine.